# Encountering blow-up when solving the one-way heat equation using Lax-Wendroff

Tags: python, finite-difference, numerics, differential-equations

This is my first time attempting to implement a finite difference method for a PDE in Python, and I am having a bit of trouble. The PDE I am trying to solve is as follows:
$$
 \begin{cases}
        v_t - 3v_x = 0, & (x,t) \in [0,1] \times [0,1] \\
        v(x,0) = 3 - 6x, & 0 \leq x \leq 1    \end{cases} 
 $$

The analytical solution is $v(x,t) = 3 - 6x - 18t$.  I am attempting to use the so-called Lax-Wendroff method:

$$
     u_k^{n+1} = u_k^{n} - \frac{R}{2}(u_{k+1}^n - u_{k-1}^n) + \frac{R^2}{2}(u_{k+1}^n - 2u_k + u_{k-1}^n), \quad k=1,2,\ldots,M-1,
$$

where $R := -3 \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}$ and $M := 1/\Delta x$  For the boundary conditions, we have
$$ u_k^0 = 3 - 6k \Delta x, \quad k = 0,1,2,\ldots,M $$

As for the spatial boundary values, I tried the following one-sided difference approximations:
\begin{align*}
    u_0^n = u_0^{n-1} + \frac{u_0^{n-1} - u_0^{n-2}}{\Delta t}, \qquad u_M^n = u_M^{n-1} + \frac{u_M^{n-1} - u_M^{n-2}}{\Delta t}, \quad n = 0,1,\ldots,N 
\end{align*}

where $N := 1/\Delta t$. Unfortunately, my solution quickly starts to blow up. I suspect this is has to do with my handling of the boundary conditions... Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#In this program we solve v_t + a*v_x = 0

a = -3 
dx = 0.01   #spatial discretization
dt = 0.01   #time discretization

M = int(1/dx)   #Number of x sub-intervals; k = 0,1,2,...,M
N = int(1/dt)   #Number of t sub-intervals; n = 0,1,2,...,N

R = (a*dt)/(dx)

#The x coordinates of the gridpoints 
x_pts = np.linspace(0, 1, M + 1, endpoint = True)

#Define the initial condition: v(x,0) = f(x)
def v_0(x):
    return 3-6*x

u = np.zeros((M+1,N+1))  #Create M+1 x N+1 array to store the solutions

#Populate the solution array with the initial condition values 
u[:,0] = v_0(x_pts)

#%%

#Each *column* of the array is the solution at time step n 

for n in range(1,N+1):     #n = 1,2,...,N

    #Handle the boundary (x = 0) 
    u[0,n] = u[0,n-1] + (u[0,n-1] - u[0,n-2])/dt 
    
    #Handle the boundary (x = 1)
    u[M,n] = u[M,n-1] + (u[M,n-1] - u[M,n-2])/dt
    
    #Lax-Wendroff scheme:
    for k in range(1,M): #k = 1,2,...,M-1 
        u[k,n] = u[k,n-1] - 0.5*R*(u[k+1,n-1] - u[k-1,n-1]) + \
                 +  0.5*(R**2)*(u[k+1,n-1] - 2*u[k,n-1] + u[k-1,n-1])
```

The plots at times $t = 0, 0.01, 0.02$ show a very rapid blow up that starts at the boundaries:
[image]

What can I do to get this scheme to work? I have tried altering the discretization parameters, but the problem doesn't go away. In theory this method should be unconditionally stable, at least according to section 5.3 of JW Thomas' numerical PDEs book...Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update 4/16/2023**: 
As @Lutz Lehman indicated in the comments, the difference quotient `(u[0,n-1] - u[0,n-2])/dt` is not defined when $n = 1$; by default Python used a value on the order of $10^{100}$ in place of $u[0,-1]$, which would explain the blow up! The following changes appear to have solved the problem:

1. I handled the boundary conditions as follows:

```
 #At x = 0, use *forward* difference approx for u_x    
    u[0,n] = u[0,n-1] - R*(u[1,n-1] - u[0,n-1])
    
    #At x = 1, use *backward* difference approx for u_x 
    u[M,n] = u[M,n-1] - R*(u[M,n-1] - u[M-1,n-1])
```

2. I realized that according to the stability theory in Thomas, we require $|R| \leq 1$ for the method to be stable. With my initial choice of discretization parameters I had $|R| = 3$, so I set `dx = 0.05` and
   `dt = 0.01` so that I now have $|R| = 0.6$.

The solution plots now appear correct!

[image]

Comment: What are the spatial boundary conditions of the undiscretized PDE problem? With none prescribed, the problem is ill-posed and there is no hope of the discrete problem being well-posed.

Comment: Leading question : What is `u[0,n-1]` if `n=1` as in the first time step? What size does consequently the difference quotient `(u[0,n-1] - u[0,n-2])/dt`? Is that within expectations?

Comment: @whpowell96: That's a good question. Apparently I need brushing up on my PDE theory, as I didn't realize the problem was ill-posed without a boundary condition. This problem actually came from a wave equation problem $u_{tt} = 9u_{xx}, \, x \in [0,1], \, t > 0$ with boundary conditions $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0, \, t > 0$ and boundary conditions $u(x,0) = x(1-x), \; x  \in [0,1]$ and $u_t(x,0) = 0, \; x \in [0,1]$. I factored the operator as $(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - 3 \frac{\partial}{\partial x})(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + 3 \frac{\partial}{\partial x})u = 0$...

Comment: Then I set $v := u_t + 3u_x$ to obtain the first order equation $v_t - 3v_x = 0$. So we should have $v(0,t) = u_t(0,t) + 3u_x(0,t) = 3u_x(0,t)$. But I'm not sure what $u_x(0,t)$ is. (Apologies, I realize this is now a math question.)